# Join three dataframes with pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark

I have three dataframes:

```
df1:                         df2:                           df3:
+--- +--------+               +--------+-------+             +----+----------+
| id1|category|               |category| values|             | id2|    values|
+----+--------+               +--------+-------+             +----+----------+ 
|   0|       C|               |       A|     v1|             |   0|    v2, v3|
|   1|       B|               |       A|     v2|             |   1|        v1|
|   2|       C|               |       A|     v3|             |   2|    v1, v3|
|   3|       A|               |       B|     v4|             |   3|v1, V2, v3|
|   4|       A|               |       B|     v5|             |   4|        v3|
|   5|       B|               |       B|     v6|             |   5|    v1, v2|
|   6|       C|               |       B|     v7|             |   6|        v3|
|   7|       A|               |       C|     v8|             +----+----------+
|   8|       B|               |       C|     v9|
|   9|       B|               |       C|    v10|
+----+--------+               |       C|    v11|
                              +--------+-------+
```

After the crossjoin between df1 and df3 via the instruction:

```
df=df1.crossJoin(df3.select("id2")).select("id1", "id2")
```

I want to add a new column (**newCloumn**) which must be filled in like this:
**1** if the *category* column contains at least one of the values in the *values* column,
**0** otherwise

Comment: can you please share how the sample output looks like ? also some of the question is not clear - "category column" which dataframe category column ? "one of the values in the values column" which dataframe values column?

Answer (score 2):

It will be more practical if you also rename the columns "category" in the two dataframes (example: category1 and category2). Try this, I think it's what you are looking for

```
df=df.select(col("id1").alias("id"), "id2")
df4=df.join(df1, df.id==df1.id1).drop("id").join(df2, df4.category1==df2.category2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work correctly with my case. Thank you for your answer